# Is it possible to dynamically change PolyLine.strokeThickness values?

Tags: c#, wpf, polyline

I'm writing a mapmaking program and I've got a very nice effect where the width of the river changes dynamically as the user draws it:

[image]

As you draw the river you can see the width increase and decrease. Here is the code:

```
   Point TempP = new Point();
                Point TempPBottom = new Point();

                int ChangeRiverSize = 0;
                int HowMuch = 0;

                ChangeRiverSize = rnd.Next(1, 11);
                if (ChangeRiverSize == 1)
                {
                    HowMuch = rnd.Next(1, 3);
                }

                polyLine.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightBlue;
                if (HowMuch == 1)
                    RiverWidth--;
                else if (HowMuch == 2)
                    RiverWidth++;

                polyLine.StrokeThickness = RiverWidth;

                TopPolyLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.CornflowerBlue);
                TopPolyLine.StrokeThickness = 2;

                BottomPolyLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.CornflowerBlue);
                BottomPolyLine.StrokeThickness = 1;

                currentPoint = e.GetPosition(MainCanvas);
                TempP = currentPoint;
                TempP.Y = TempP.Y - (RiverWidth / 2);

                TempPBottom = currentPoint;
                TempPBottom.Y = TempPBottom.Y + (RiverWidth / 2);

                polygonPoints.Add(currentPoint);
                TopPolygonPoints.Add(TempP);
                BottomPolygonPoints.Add(TempPBottom);

                polyLine.Points = polygonPoints;
                TopPolyLine.Points = TopPolygonPoints;
                BottomPolyLine.Points = BottomPolygonPoints;
```

The problem is that when the user lets up on the mouse button it seems that the river goes back to a uniform width. The fact that the two riverbanks move in and out fool the eye, however.

I'm thinking that a polyline can only have one width for the entire length of the line. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: A river on a map is usually a filled area, not a stroked line.

Comment: I do fills for lakes, forests & swamps. I was just hoping to do this with a stroked line.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm thinking that a polyline can only have one width for the entire length of the line. Is there anyway around this?

No, you have to use a filled area instead.